# Getting suspended/hibernated the laptop automatically after upgrade from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 in my laptop

Tags: upgrade

After upgrading from Ubuntu  17.04 to 17.10 on my laptop, it gets suspended every now and then and had to use the power button pressed to bring back the login screen, but this repeats almost every 15 seconds or so and unable to use.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings->power->power saving-> Turn off the dim when inactive

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your response. The issue remains same even after turning off the above suggested option.

Answer (score 0):

I had reinstalled 17.04 and  set the option **Settings > Power > when the lid is closed to "Do Nothing"** from default **"suspend"** to resolve the problem.

These options were not found in 17.10